# Difference between memory usage outputs via 'neofetch' and 'free -m'

Tags: command-line, bash, ram

I wanted to write a script to check my RAM usage at regular intervals and then calculate its maximum.

To calculate the used Memory, I had two options, via `neofetch` or `free -m`

The output of `$ free -m` gives:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15839        4169        7630         794        4039       10555
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

So, I piped the output as `$ free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print ($3/1024)}'` which results in `4.07324` .

Now, if I do something similar to `$neofetch` output as, `$ neofetch | grep -i Memory | awk '{print ($2/1024)}'`, I get the output as `4.84668`

Thus, these 2 outputs do not match up, which one is to be considered for checking the actual RAM usage?
If it matters, I have a 4gb GTX1650 running Nvidia drivers, and consuming `53MB` RAM when checked via `$ nvidia-smi`

---

One of the possible situations I can think of, is where `$ neofetch` gives me the Used memory and the shared memory, since the outputs of

`$ free -m | grep Mem | awk '{print (($3+$5)/1024)}'`

and

`$ neofetch | grep -i Memory | awk '{print ($2/1024)}'`

are very close to each other (`4.85547` and `4.86035`)

But my question remains, which memory values to trust?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using `free -m` or `cat /proc/meminfo` for your source of memory usage. These numbers come directly from the kernel.

Here, the number used memory is calculated as:

```
# used = total - free - buffers/cache
```

Neofetch calculates memory usage from `cat /proc/meminfo`, and as you guessed, it shows
used memory including the "shared" part: (source code, line 2679):

```
# MemUsed = Memtotal + Shmem - MemFree - Buffers - Cached - SReclaimable
```

I believe the number from `free` is the most reliable. But since memory usage can be complex, there isn't a simple answer. You'll have to ask the developers of Neofetch why they have calculated it as they do.

Comment: I suspect neofetch' approach may be simply wrong. I think `shared` is part of `used`, which is supported by the fact that `used + free + buff/cache = total`.

Comment: Ahh thanks, i get it, I'll go with the ```free -m``` output for now.

Answer (score 4):

You should only look at the "Available" section of the `free` output. A lot of RAM on Linux system is shown as "used" by various tools, including neofetch, because it is used for caching, but it is released as soon as any program needs it (this is shown in the "buff/cache"). So although not technically "free", that memory is available, and *that* is what you really want to know: how much memory is available to the system.

So change your parsing to:

```
free -m | awk '$1=="Mem:"{print $7}'
```

This will give you the number under `available` which is what you really want. Neofetch, on the other hand, seems to be reporting just "used" + "shared" but that isn't correctly reporting the amount of memory currently available to a new process on your system.

Useful references:

- https://www.linuxatemyram.com/
- [How can I get the amount of available memory portably across distributions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261247/)

Comment: _"You should only look at the "Available" section of the free output."_ - Nonsense; all those fields have value, you just have to know what you're looking at. In particular: _"A lot of RAM on Linux system is shown as "used" because it is used for caching ..."_ - `used` does not include caches. If you want to know how much memory is used by applications, `used` is _exactly_ what you should look at. `available` does not help you there.

Comment: @marcelm first of all, please mind your tone. Second, of course they have value, good grief! They are just not what the OP is looking for here. And by "used" I meant it is shown as used, not that it is under the "used" column of `free` output, that was unclear and I have edited it.

Comment: _"They are just not what the OP is looking for here"_ - OP is asking about memory in use. They don't need `available`, they need `used`. And possibly `buff/cache`, depending on their definition of "in use"; but in my experience, the overwhelming majority of people asking about "memory usage" are not interested in cache usage, hence linuxatemyram.com's existence.

Comment: In my experience, the overwhelming majority of people asking about memory usage are trying to answer the question "how much memory is available to processes now?". Which is why I focused on that. But since you made it clear you think that's "nonsense", let's leave it at that.

Comment: I want to check the net memory used since this snippet will be used to run a code on a 32gb Ram machine, i want to check if the max memory usage crosses 16gb since my laptop has a16gb ram stick and i eventually want to run the code there.

Comment: @Luce but how do you define "used"? If memory is being used for caching, but will be immediately released as soon as any process requests memory, does it count as used? Linux will try and use as much memory as possible, so it _will_ pass 16G if you look at used, that's why you should instead look at "available". This is why it isn't a problem on Linux when memory usage appears high, it is only a problem if the "available" memory is too low. For example,  my 32G machine currently shows only 2.2G "free", but 18G "available".